# Creating a multi-indexed DataFrame from a list of values (and writing this to SQL)

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine I have a list of calculated results on my data, such as

```
r = [['aln1', 'classifier1', True], ['aln1', 'classifier2', False]]
```

I want to construct a `DataFrame` where the first two columns form a `MultiIndex`, which can then be written to SQL as a index. I don't particularly care if the index is used internally in Pandas or not.

I can convert `r` into a DataFrame easily, recording the column names:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(r, columns=['AlignmentId', 'Classifier', 'Value'])
```

Which produces a `DataFrame` with a numerical index, and 3 columns:

```
  AlignmentId   Classifier  Value
0        aln1  classifier1   True
1        aln1  classifier2  False
```

How can I either A) Write this directly to SQL, and create a index `AlignmentId -> Classifier`, or B) impose such a index directly during `DataFrame` construction, which would then be created upon writing to SQL?

Comment: If `AlignmentId` and `Classifier` are together unique, the easiest way to create a multiindex is to do `df.groupby(['AlignmentId', 'Classifier']).first()`.

Comment: @Kris Or rather `df = df.set_index(['AlignmentId', 'Classifier'])`. Doesn't matter if the index is unique or not. Besides, `groupby` is doing some extra job we don't need or use.

Comment: @pjtr brilliant, even better